# Using value of a variable when assigning a formula to a cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

How can I replace the `999` with the value of a variable in my code below?

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(RC[-1]>=GSV!R[-3]C12,999,IF(RC[-1]<=GSV!R[-3]C13,2,1))"
                              ^^^
```

I tried `[" & variable & "]` without success (even though it works for the rows and columns).

Answer (score 1):

You tried `[" & variable & "]` but you don't need the `[` square brackets `]`.

Just `" & variable & "` will do:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(RC[-1]>=GSV!R[-3]C12," & variable & ",IF(RC[-1]<=GSV!R[-3]C13,2,1))"
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```